# Same routes.rb different routes using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I have 2 Rails 4.0.1 projects using the same version of devise. They have identical `config/initializers/devise.rb` and both have this line in the `config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for  :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks",  registrations: "users"}
```

In the application that works I get this output in the `rake routes`, but not in the app that doesn't:

```
 user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)                    users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/github/}
  user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)             users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:github)
```

Does anyone know why this would work in one app but not another? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: long shot but what do you get with `cat Gemfile.lock | grep devise`?

Comment: Figured it out by working backwards (making the working app fail). My model was missing a `:omniauthable` in the `devise` class method. #head_desk